# C++: Cannot instantiate my class with new

Tags: c++, types

With Eclipse CDT I've written an abstract class 'Lexer' that resides in a shared library project. It is inherited by 'UTF8Lexer' in another shared library project. For these I created a UnitTest++ test project that contains the following code:

```
#include "UnitTest++.h"
#include "UTF8Lexer.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

programma::Lexer<UChar32, icu::UnicodeString>* getLexer(string sampleFile)
{
    string path = "../samples/" + sampleFile;

    ifstream* stream = new ifstream();
    stream->open (path.data());

    programma::UTF8Lexer l1(stream); //This line compiles fine.

    programma::UTF8Lexer* l2 = new  programma::UTF8Lexer(stream); // Error: "Type 'programma::UTF8Lexer' could not be resolved"

    return l2;
}
```

I don't understand why he likes the declaration of l1 but dislikes the one of l2... The typically unspecific error message doesn't give me much of a clue (Though I'm new to C++, I've worked a lot with C# and made some things in C during my computer science courses at university...). I think it cannot be any missing reference or include because it actually processes the l1 declaration... But if I create some other class right in the same source file and instantiate it the same way, everything works...

I used [this tutorial](http://linuxtortures.blogspot.de/2012/02/shared-libraries-with-eclipse.html) to connect the libraries to their using projects, so this should be fine.

I also googled a lot for this, but as it turned out, it's either impossible to find specific search terms for this problem or I've found some sort of special case...

Here are some excerpts from the classes mentioned above:

- UTF8Lexer.h:

  ```
  #ifndef UTF8LEXER_H_
  #define UTF8LEXER_H_


  #include "unicode/unistr.h"
  #include "Lexer.h"
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace icu;

  namespace programma {

  class UTF8Lexer : public Lexer<UChar32, UnicodeString> {

  public:

      UTF8Lexer(std::istream* source);

      ~UTF8Lexer();
  ...
  ```
- UTF8Lexer.cpp:

  ```
  #include "UTF8Lexer.h"

  namespace programma {

  programma::UTF8Lexer::UTF8Lexer(std::istream* source)
  {
  }

  programma::UTF8Lexer::~UTF8Lexer() {

  }
  ...
  ```
- Lexer.h:

  ```
  #ifndef LEXER_H_
  #define LEXER_H_

  #include "Token.h"

  namespace programma {

  template<typename C, typename S> class Lexer {
  public:
  ...
  ```

Comment: What compiler are you using that's giving you the error message? (Internal Eclipse errors are hit-and-miss and not worth trying to debug, so I'm assuming it's a proper compile error you're showing us.)

Comment: I'm using the GNU C++ toolchain and yes, it's a proper compiler error.

Comment: in UTF8Lexer.cpp, you don't need the programma::, since you're in the programma namespace already.

Comment: I should mention that the declaration of l1 was only added to demonstrate, that instantiating UTF8Lexer works indeed. Only allocating an instance of the heap using 'new' fails...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what's causing my trouble: Properly enaming 'UTF8Lexer' to 'UTFLexer' solved everything. But then, a few hours later, I had the same problem with a class member. Minutes away from disposing of this seemingly totally defunct Eclipse/CDT/GCC setup, I had the idea of rebuilding the index for the project: Just right click on the project, select "Index"->"Rebuild". Now it works.

Comment: Does someone know, what the Eclipse index has to do with the GNU compiler? Why does one influence the other?

Answer (score 0):

`programma::UTF8Lexer l1(stream);` is probably parsed as `programma::UTF8Lexer l1(std::stream __Unnamed_Argument);`, i.e. a declaration of a function named `l1`. Remove `using namespace std::` to fix this.

Comment: Is `stream` really a member of `std::` and even if `l1` is parsed as a function, why would that affect the parsing of the next line?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Possibly, it's up to the implementation. It doesn't affect the parsing of the next line, but the function declaration does compile even if `programma::UTF8Lexer` is an incomplete type.

Comment: AFAIK, it shouldn't be up to the implementation. If `stream` isn't explicitly part of `std::` then as it doesn't start with `_` or contain `__` it's allowed for users to use as, say, a macro so shouldn't be used for any conflicting purposes by the standard library implementation.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: It's true that you're allowed to define such a macro, but that doesn't have to conflict with `std::`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at. Are you saying that the implementation _is_ allowed to define `stream` in the `std` namespace in a standard header file?

Comment: @CharlesBailey: yes, if it does so in a way that doesn't conflict with your macros. That may require implementation magic (`#pragma undef(stream) / #pragma redef(stream)`, I'm not sure.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry if my use of a macro as an example has caused confusion. You may be right, but I was under the impression that names not specifically mention in the standard library section couldn't be used by the implementation unless they were explicitly reserved for the implementation because of things _like_ macros or colliding `using namespace` issues.

Comment: Removing 'using namespace std;' and renaming the variable 'stream' to 'myStream' doesn't change anything.